# oops, coupling and opengl

Tags: oop, opengl, graphics

Coupling seems to be bad programming practice. Why do OOPS advocate this paradigm? As an example, I viewed Java, .net and Android rectangle classes. Each defined differently. Furthermore you must instantiate a rectangle to draw it.

With OpenGL, drawing a rectangle is not coupled to a rectangle object. This decoupling the drawing of a rectangle from the object makes the API more robust. You can draw a rectangle as a lambda-like function - without creating a rectangle object at all.

Coupling actions to objects may be a way of abstracting functionality or making components. Yet to me it seems to limit usage and enforce all or nothing. Either use my objects and methods or nothing. Then a proliferation of the same objects defined differently with differing methods ensued.

Libraries tend to decompose the object's fields into the parameters necessary to accomplish a task. This adds to the function name only. E.g. in oops it will be "rectangle.draw()" in opengl it will be: "drawRectangle(x1,y1,x2,Y2)".

Why does oops couple drawing to the shape. Seems bizarre. Also, if draw methods accessed hardware and a new GPU was added, every object must be changed vs just changing the drawing methods if not coupled.

Is graphics a domain where oops abstraction is not the best approach is a better refined question.

With oops we don't just define an object like a c struct, we then define what can be done with the object, which varies greatly. Then we couple what can be done with the object to the object. This leads to varying definitions of the same objects. And no one can assume to know all that can be done to an object.

For instance, we may want to bisect a rectangle. Add a new bisect method to a rectangle object or create a bisect function That takes a rectangle structure. As new functionality is added, a structure doesn't change but the object's methods will, thus changing the object since they are closely coupled.

Consensus may then be reached on structure. Eg. A rectangle is a structure with a length and width Represented as numbers. What you can do with a rectangle depends on what library you choose.

Comment: What is "OOPS"? Also, OpenGL has no `drawRectangle`.

Comment: Oops is object oriented programming systems.  In opengl it's something like "glrectf(parameters)" to draw a rectangle. Not rectangle.gldrawf().

Comment: I was stressing that opengl seems to take a functional approach like c, not oops approach like c++. In the sense that opengl functions aren't explicitly tied to objects, maybe implicitly tied to graphic driver objects.

Comment: "*Oops is object oriented programming systems.*" [This is the first site I found via Google that uses this abbreviation in that way](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/92174/28374), and most of the answers recommend just using OOP. Also, abbreviations are capitalized.

Comment: Typing from cell phone. An example: the glrectf(2,2,4,4) takes four parameters. Now suppose this same function took a rectangle structure or structure pointer. Then it would appear as gldraw (rectangle r) binding the drawing to a rectangle structure. What OOP does is make the rectangle an object and the code would appear as myRectangle.gldraw(). This is not done. My guess is because it will couple functions to objects and limit reusability. Am I right?

Comment: Seems the difference is in a library vs class libraries. If you want to make universally applicable code, create a library. If you want to restrict code to be only applicable from your own conceived view of classes and objects create a class library. This may work in some instances, but it seems that class libraries are not used much in the graphics arena. I may be wrong. But I don't care how .net or java or android defines a rectangle in a hierarchy to oblivion. I just want to  be able to draw one easily. Opengl seems a better fit.

Comment: @Daryl: Functional ≠ Imperative. C most certainly is not a functional language (i.e. functions as first order objects). C by far is a purely *imperative* programming language. You sort of can introduce constructs that resemble functional programming into C, but you'll never get things like function composition. If you want to have a look at functional programming, look at OCaml, Haskell, Erlang, Scheme, Lisp, Closure or Scala. OpenGL most certainly is not functional due to its global state; it's clearly imperative and very difficult to bind into pure functional languages.

Comment: @Daryl: The more you say, the less you sound like someone trying to genuinely understand something and the more you sound like someone trying to justify their already-determined ideas. Stack Overflow is not for rants disguised as questions.

Comment: My mistake, imperative. Don't want to rant. Its a design decision. If I want to create a graphics library, is classed based or imperative based the best route to take for robustness. It seems opengl is imperative based, while java and .net used a class based library approach.

Comment: My ideas were set at first I thought class based was the only way to go. Then I researched Grand Theft Auto, which seems to take an imperative/procedural approach written on top of game engines and rendering physics engines.

Comment: The pure virtual functions and dynamic binding was my reasoning for choosing OOP. Then I recognized that a DLL provides the same functionality as dynamic binding without the object overhead. I don't want to rant. But graphics programming is very prolific and there are engines that seem to be more robust when a procedural approach is applied. Anyone can use them Regardless of their class hierarchy. Is this the most accessible approach?

Answer (score 0):

I will answer first. Developing 3 tier systems, with an SQL back end, business objects as the middle tier and the GUI as the front tier, obliviates OOP. With c#, so much repetition. Your defining things 3 times.

I mean SQL is the ultimate in data abstraction. CRUD behavior. Create, read. Update. Delete. Treats data like the fetch decode exe loop of interpretation REPL.

IS these operations tied to an object? Are Assembly instructions object based. Mov Ax, Bx. In OOP this would be Ax.mov(BX) binding operations to objects or registers.

Not ranting.